# Периодические задачи не вызываются в Django

Tags: python, django, cron

В моём проекте есть периодические задачи. Проблема в том, что они не вызываются.

Я создал тестовую функцию, которая отправляет мне сообщение, и я пойму, что задача выполнена:

```py
def test_crj():
    send_message("Test cronjobs!")
```

Запуск настроил на раз в 5 минут:

```py
# in settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ... ,
    "django_crontab",
]
CRONJOBS = [
    ("*/5 * * * *", "project.cronjob.test_crj", '>> /tmp/test.log'),
]
```

`crontab` видит задачи:

```bash
> docker exec container python3.9 manage.py crontab show
# Currently active jobs in crontab:
# a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f -> ('*/5 * * * *', 'project.cronjob.test_crj', '>> /tmp/test.log')

> docker exec container crontab -l
# */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /app/manage.py crontab run a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f >> /tmp/test.log # django-cronjobs for project
```

Но ничего не происходит! При этом запуск функции отдельно (например, в `manage.py shell`) работает нормально. И если я запускаю командой, которую должен запускать `crontab` (как я это понимаю), всё работает.

```bash
> docker exec container python3.9 manage.py crontab run a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f
# it works
```

В чём может быть ошибка и кто виноват - `django_crontab` или системный `crontab`И где и как я могу найти в логах, что именно не работает?

UPD:
Я внутри контейнера руками создал задачу `/1 * * * * echo 'Hello!' >> /tmp/test.txt`, и она корректно отрабатывает.

Также когда внутри контейнера вызываю такое строкой, то тоже всё нормально работает.

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /app/manage.py crontab run a35573388f4e46c33f88fc825f0a1d8f >> /tmp/test.log # django-cronjobs for project
```

Но раз в пять минут почему-то упорно не хочет вызываться.

Comment: Системный crontab тоже должен быть кем-то запущен

Comment: @andreymal а как это проверить? `service cron restart` в контейнере делал, `crontab` на обращения вроде реагирует.